# MongoDB: Lock and unlock collection manually

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to perform a transactional read and then write depending on the results.

Reads should be queud until the read and write is done and I manually unlocked the collection.

Is that possible?

Comment: No, there are no transaction in mongodb yet. Should be in v4.0: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/upcoming/#upcoming-features-in-4-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Reads should be queued until the read and write is done and I manually unlocked the collection.

Locking the collection manually is **not** supported in [MongoDB Transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions).

What you have described is a [Pessimistic Locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_locking) behaviour. Where documents selected are locked until the transaction commits or rolls back, which potentially could cause [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

MongoDB Transactions utilises [Optimistic Locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control). It's a strategy where an internal version number is recorded when document(s) are read. When the document(s) are written back, check that the version has not been changed (by other processes outside of the transaction).

If the document's version is different than what's recorded at the start of the transaction, the transaction is aborted and it can be retried again (depending on the requirements).

See also [MongoDB Transactions manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/) for more information.

Additional information: Multi-documents transactions are available in MongoDB v4+. MongoDB v4.0.0-rc0 (Release Candidate) was released on 23rd May 2018.

Comment: Wow, awesome stuff. With "it can be retried again" I assume there wont be an option to "retry until successfull" and I will have to implement that logic myself, is that right?

Comment: Correct. You would have to implement that on your application. Deal with the transactions failure accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I read mongo documentation but I couldn't find anything easy to use and mantain for my project, so I got this idea which is actually working pretty good and it's super simple and easy to use.

- First you define a Lock model where the _id is the name of the collection

  ```
   import pkg from 'mongoose';                                         
   const {Schema, model} = pkg;                                        
   const lockSchema = new Schema(
   {
       _id: {
           type: String,
           required: true
       },
       isLocked: {
           type: Boolean,
           required: true
       }
   },
   {timestamps: true}                                               
   );                                                                 
   export const Lock = model('Lock', lockSchema, 'locks');
  ```
- Then you define a middleware when you can check if the interested collection is locked (in this case you just return an error, but you could store the request in a queue so that when the collection is no more locked you process the request)

  ```
   import {Lock} from "../models/Lock.js";                            
   export const USERS_COLLECTION= 'users';                   

   export const lock = async (req, res, next) => {                     

   const {isLocked} = await Lock.findById(USERS_COLLECTION);   
   if (isLocked) {
       return res.status(409).send('operation not available for possible 
   conflict states, retry in a few seconds'); }                                                                   

   next();                                                                 
   }
  ```
- Finally in your router function, when you have multiple read and write operations with concurrency issue you **lock the collection before the first IO operation** and you **unlock the collection just before you send back the response or in case of error in the catch block**

  ```
  router.post('/users', lock, (req, res) => {                                   

  try{                                                                    
      await Lock.findByIdAndUpdate(USERS_COLLECTION, {isLocked: true});

       // multiple read/write operations on user collection                                                                                                                           

      await Lock.findByIdAndUpdate(USERS_COLLECTION, {isLocked: false});                                                                    
      res.send();                                                                                                                   
    }                                                               

  catch {                                                                                                                             
      await Lock.findByIdAndUpdate(USERS_COLLECTION, {isLocked: false});                                                   

      res.status(500).send();                                                                    
    }                                                          

  })
  ```