# Strange behavior on when I press button many times very quick in NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, angular

I have got 2 cards with 2 candidates, every candidate has a button where user can have a unique vote, the card have a box with **total** votes also, if the user make a vote for the first candidate, then the value of **total** in both cards is updated (in a card is substracted in another is added), . But when I press the button many times and very fast, the data returned by the backend is incorrect. Someone can explain what is happening please.

---

TEMPLATE OF COMPONENT IN ANGULAR

> 

```
<mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let candidate of candidates; let i = index">

    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-raised-button class="button-vote" (click)="saveVote(candidate.userVotes[0], candidate)">
            <mat-icon color="accent" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon">pan_tool</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <div class="result" mat-fab>{{candidate.totalVotes}} votos</div>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

---

COMPONENENT.TS

> 

```
export class CandidatesContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  candidates!: any[]
  constructor(
    private candidatesService: CandidatesService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtainCandidates()
  }
  obtainCandidates() {
    this.candidatesService.getCandidates().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.candidates = response
    })
  }
  saveVote(userVote: any, candidate: object | any) {
    this.candidatesService.updateVote(candidate._id, userVote.thisChoosed).subscribe(response => {
      if (response) {
        this.obtainCandidates()
      }
    })
  }


}
```

---

CONTROLLER IN NODE.JS

> 

```
const updateVote = async ( req = request, res = response ) => {
    const { candidateId, thisChoosed } = req.params

    const query = thisChoosed === 'true' ? candidateId: { $ne:candidateId }

    const previousVote = await Candidate.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id:query },
        { 
            '$set': { 'userVotes.$[el].thisChoose': false }, 
            '$inc': { 'totalVotes':  -1 } 
        },
        { arrayFilters: [ 
            {"el.user": req.user._id }]
        }
    )

    const newVote = await Candidate.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id:candidateId },
        { 
            '$set': { 'userVotes.$[el].thisChoose': true }, 
            '$inc': { 'totalVotes': 1 } 
        },
        { 
            arrayFilters: [ {"el.user": req.user._id }, ], new:true
        }
        
    )
    res.json( newVote )
}
```

---

DATABASE

```
const VoteSchema = Schema({
    user:{
        type:Schema.ObjectId,
        ref:'User',
        required:[true, 'User is required - vote user']
    },
    thisChoosed:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    firstVote:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:true
    }
})

const CandidateSchema = Schema({
    names:{
        type:String,
        required:[true]
    },
    surnames:{
        type:String,
        required:[true]
    },
    userVotes:[VoteSchema],
    totalVotes:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
})
```

Comment: the expected  result is substact 1 in a candidate an add 1 in another, but when I press many times an quickly the button, result is for instance ( 0 - 2), (-1, 4), or (-2, 5)

Comment: You have a race condition.  You are doing two database operations, one after the other.  But, other requests arriving at about the same time and affecting the same parts of the database can get in between them and mess up your expected results such that some other DB operation affecting the same part of the data got in between your two requests.  I don't know your database well enough to know what to suggest for it.  Typical solutions include a sequencing queue, a temporary DB lock, a transaction, fitting everything into one atomic db operation, etc...

Comment: according to this link ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50608882/mongodb-lock-and-unlock-collection-manually ) , I can't to lock manually database, mongodb lock for us. In the documentation explain that we can lock a database, collection or documents but they aren't examples for it. By the way I added my database in this question

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're running in to?  The result `res.json( newVote )` is as of the moment of the last database call - it's never guaranteed to be current if another DB calls comes immediately after it and changes the value.  Please describe exactly what you observe as the problem and exactly what you expect the result to be.  And, describe whether this is a database integrity issue or just a display issue?

Comment: Initial state of votes for every candidate in database   : totalVotes: 1   ---  totalVotes: 0. Desired state after to make  a vote: totalVotes: 2   ---    totalVotes: 0. The problem only after to press many times the button: totalVotes: 4    ---   totalVotes: -1. The problem is in database. I need to keep correct state of totalVotes for every candidate despite to receive many updates for that field.